# What's the proper way to have child components act on parent data when there is a generic intermediate styling component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have several components that need to both filter and sort displayed data based on controls the user manipulates. This particular combination (filter & sort) is used in more than one place, so it makes sense to componentize the controls as a group for common styling and layout. The relationship looks like:

Report 1 --> headerControl [with CSS styling] ---> filterControl,sortControl,displayModeControl
Report 2 --> headerControl [with CSS styling] ---> filterControl,sortControl

Each report (parent component) needs to pass data in through headerControl and into the individual controls which will filter, sort, etc.. and pass data back up to the report. But headerControl is generic and so does not know what individual controls are desired, nor what bindings they each need. It's job is just to group the controls in a flexbox and style them with CSS. Because Svelte's bind: doesn't permit spreading the way props do, the only way to make headerControl generic is to have a single bind object share with all child controls and each control sets a property of its own in that object. Eg.:

Parent report component:

```
  // define which child controls are wanted and set up props each of them need
  $: headerControlArgs=[{
      component: FilterControl,
      args: {
        ...
      }
    },{
      component: SortControl,
      args: {
        ...
      }
    }
  ]

// create a generic object to receive the binds back
let headerControlBinds={
  sort: undefined,
  filter: undefined
}

// when the functions show up from the bindings, call them
  $: filteredData = (data?.length > 0 && typeof headerControlBinds.filter !== "undefined")?headerControlBinds.filter(data) : []

  $: sortedData = (filteredData?.length > 0 && typeof headerControlBinds.sort !== "undefined")?headerControlBinds.sort(filteredData) : []


 <HeaderControls items={headerControlArgs} bind:binds={headerControlBinds} />
```

Within HeaderControls:

```
  {#each items as item}
    <svelte:component this={item.component} {...item.args} bind:binds={binds} />
  {/each}
```

And finally within the sort and filter controls at the bottom of the stack:

$: binds.filter = (data) => ... [function that filters]

$: binds.sort = (data) => ... [function that sorts]

But it seems awfully inelegant, for the following reasons:

(1) I have to do all these checks to wait for the child components to be rendered and the binds to complete before I can call the functions. Before that, the functions don't exist.

(2) I have to use a common object to receive the binds coming from the child components, since my middle HeaderControl component is generic and does not know what bindings will be passed through it.

(3) I have to set up the argument list for input to these controls using custom array of objects and their arguments/props instead of using normal individual properties on the control itself, since HeaderControls doesn't know which properties to send to which child controls.

(4) the component array and arguments have to be separated from the binds so they don't cause a reaction cycle. But logically it would be cleaner if the bind variable were part of the same array (for each component, what component is it, what args to pass in, what binds to receive back).

The only other option that I can think of is to use slots. But Svelte doesn't support dynamic slot naming, so we're back to hardcoding a fixed list of slots with fixed names and we're no longer dynamic:

[in HeaderControls]:

```
  {#if $$slots.slot1}
   <slot name="slot1"></slot>
  {/if}
  {#if $$slots.slot2}
   <slot name="slot2"></slot>
  {/if}
  {#if $$slots.slot3}
   <slot name="slot3"></slot>
  {/if}
  {#if $$slots.slot4}
   <slot name="slot4"></slot>
  {/if}
```

called by:

```
<HeaderControls>
  <span slot="slot1">
    <FilterControl
      {data}
      bind:filteredData={filteredData}
    />
  </span>
  <span slot="slot2">
    <SortControl
      data={filteredData}
      bind:sortedData={sortedData}
    />
  </span>
</HeaderControls>
```

We should not be having to name things "slot1", "slot2", etc. Plus having to add unnecessary spans or divs in order to specify slots seems off as well.

There is discussion out there about dynamically named slots being un-Svelty and developers are directed instead to svelte:component. But as explained above, because of the lack of spread capability on binds, we cannot generically/dynamically set up binding through that mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is see if you could use a slot instead of svelte:component for the HeaderControls, basically:

```
<HeaderControls>
  <FilterControl bind:filter />
  <SortControl bind:sort />
  <SearchControl bind:search />
</HeaderControls>
```

This would link your control directly with the import.

If that is not possible, from your options "using stores" would be the best for your solution.
One thing to keep in mind those that stores are usually shared across the **entire** application, which you might not want if you have for example several reports.  In that case you can use a context: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext

That would mean you create a store (you need this because contexts are not reactive) in the Report component and put in the context with `setContext`, then in your controls you can get this context with `getContext`.

Comment: How do you get HeaderControls to slot those three components?

Comment: you put a `<slot />` element where you want it to add the children

Comment: Yes, but HeaderControls doesn't know how many slots are needed, nor what to name them. Attempt to programmatically create slots within an {#each} loop runs into Svelte's refusal to let you programmatically give a slot a name.

Comment: In the example you gave (added after this answer if I am not mistaken) you don't exactly need those named slots though.  If you absolutely need them, you either wrap them with an element as you say, or use the context api.

Comment: If I don't need the named slots, can I put content into multiple slots without naming them? It's not mainly an issue of using bogus elements, it's more an issue of having to come up with a hardcoded naming convention like "slot1" "slot2", etc.. not sure how it's possible any other way using slots.  Stores and context I want to stay away from and keep my data flow locally contained. This really should be very simple... there must be way to create a common CSS styling component that can wrap around other components without removing the flexibility of setting up binds through the intermediate.

Comment: you can multiple elements in one slot. only use named slots if you have more markup seperating those slots and you really want specific children in specific places like a layout component with a slot for header, sidebar, content, footer, ...  Your example doesn't reflect such a need

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was missing! I didn't realize I could simply put multiple components between the opening and closing wrapper component tags and have them all rendered in a single slot. That works perfectly!